# Change position of an added form field in Symfony

Tags: symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have created the form in Symfony 1.4/Doctrine) that is generated from the schema i can manipulate the field labels, the validation, modifying the widgets to get data from the db and can generate a new filed that is not in the schema.

The problem is the form is generated by $form variable and the the new field i create is at the bottom of this set of fields. How do i insert it somewhere in the schema generated fields.

Note . All i want to do is have Password and Confirm Password. Password is onviously in the schema but Confirm Password is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make any change by rendering each field separately in your template or view. For example, if you have user, password and confirm_password fields you can do:

```
//template or view
<?php echo $form['user']->renderRow()?><br/>
<?php echo $form['password']->renderRow()?><br/>
<?php echo $form['confirm_password']->renderRow()?>
```

if you want to do more complex things see [Jobeet Form Example](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/10)

Comment: Thanks, i keep iterating through the Jobeet/more-with-symfony and more of it makes sense each time, i had the feeling that your answer was the way to go but wanted to be sure i wasn't missing something blindingly simple.

Answer (score 2):

sfForm::useFields() is a new function to symfony 1.3 that allows the developer to specify exactly which fields the form should use and in which order they should be displayed. All other non-hidden fields are removed from the form.

from
[More With Forms Symfony 1.4](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setPositions` from the `WidgetSchema` to set positions of all your fields:

```
<?php

$this->getWidgetSchema()->setPositions(array(
    0 => 'field_one',
    1 => 'field_two',
    // etc...
));
```

Or you can "move" a field across the form with `moveField`:

```
<?php

// Moving to top
$this->getWidgetSchema()->moveField('field_one', sfWidgetFormSchema::FIRST);
// Moving before 'field_two'
$this->getWidgetSchema()->moveField('field_three', sfWidgetFormSchema::BEFORE, 'field_two');

//    *  Available actions are:
//    *
//    *  sfWidgetFormSchema::BEFORE
//    *  sfWidgetFormSchema::AFTER
//    *  sfWidgetFormSchema::LAST
//    *  sfWidgetFormSchema::FIRST
```